# How is a long retrieved from the getInt() function in Android programming?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

In the Android Developer documentation on creating a new app, when it talks about retrieving values from Shared Preferences, for values with the data type `long` it uses the `getInt()` method, and then uses the `getString()` method. Why are `getInt()` and `getString()` used when a long is neither an integer nor a string, why is `getString()` used for `int` also, and what's the difference between `getInteger()` and `getInt()`?

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Comment: "In the Android Developer documentation" -- please provide a link to where the documentation says what you think it says. In your code snippet, there is no `long`, and neither `getInteger()` nor `getString()` are being called on the `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

The `int` datatype is just been cast to a `long`, as you can check [here](https://ideone.com/Ld4tm6):

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long a = getInt("1");
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    private static int getInt(String letter){
        return Integer.parseInt(letter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store a long value in the SharedPreferences, your best bet is to store it as a long, with the use of `putLong()` and `getLong()`. Those are the right methods as you will avoid unnecessary parses and loss of information.

[This link provides an intro to the usage of SharedPreferences.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)